# How to get warning if picturebox is empty

Tags: c#, .net

How can I get the warning message for this code?

```
byte[] imageBt = null;
FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
```

I have a `PictureBox` and its empty and every time I'am going to click the "save" button it shows me an error:

[image]

Comment: What dies any of that code have to do with a picturebox?

Comment: the line of Filestream

Comment: @VhongMarvinNavarraVillanuev Open your eyes, that line of code only contains an (empty) textBox.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with user input you should always validate it to make sure it is valid. In this particular case the error is telling you that the `textBox1.Text` value is empty. You should check for that:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    //input is empty, error?
}
```

As you are trying to load a file it would also be best to make sure that the file exists:

```
if (!File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
{
    //file doesn't exist, error?
}
```

As always there are extra validation checks that can be done, for example:

- If the supplied string is a valid path
- If the supplied string is a valid path to a file
- etc.

But at some point you have to draw the line as to how many checks are too many.

Comment: You should not use `File.Exists` to determine if path to the file is valid.

Comment: Which is wrong because of the user/application rights. Read about that on msdn.

Comment: @m.rogalski If I remember correctly `File.Exists` returns false if the user doesn't have permissions to access the file, which I'd say is expected behaviour. I don't see your point.

Comment: You said "I'm using it to determine if the file exists" but then you stated that you don't really care about that the file exists but if user has access to it. Which makes no sense,

Comment: @m.rogalski The OP is loading the file, `File.Exists` returns true if the file exists and the user has permissions to read the file, else false. That was what my previous comment was about. `File.Exists` is the perfect method for checking if you can read a file at that time, albeit it does have some race conditions. I'm really having trouble trying to see what your point is.

Answer (score 1):

As from exception text - this error has nothing to do with emptiness of `pictureBox`, but you haven't specified name of file you're writing the data into (because `textBox1` contains no text).

So add check like

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
{
  //do whatever you need, show your warning
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an empty path name here:

```
new FileStream(this.textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

In order to prevent that, first check if the path name is empty:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text))
{
    // the input is empty, show an error?
}
```

Basically, if there's an error condition, stop processing the request and return control to the user with an error message of some kind.  This *could* be as simple as a `MessageBox()` and a `return;`.

Comment: It looks like you have unnecessary logical negation in condition.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev: Good catch, thanks!  I guess I'm really used to the inverse on that one for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

If you actually want the error message, then wrap your code in a try catch block like:

```
try
{
    byte[] imageBt = null;
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
}
catch(Exception error)
{
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: his question was "How can I get the warning message for this code?" so this answers that.

Comment: The error message is in the question, the user has that. The user also states that they are using a PictureBox when none is shown so you can't really take their word for it...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder This is the only valid answer in here. Rest of the guys are making only the checks if the string is empty or contains only white spaces. Meaning if I put there "Z:\some_imaginary_folder\file.txt" it will pass their checks but throws another exception...

Comment: @m.rogalski When dealing with paths you should check if the string is not null or empty, the file exists etc. In this case I'd say full validation before loading from random user input is actually the correct answer, of which none of the current answers show this. The answer to the question is checking for an empty string though as that is what the error message shows. Blindly catching any random exception is never an answer.

Comment: Using exceptions for logic flow is a famously bad idea.  Conditions can be checked very easily.

Comment: I agree, but that was not what he asked, he asked how to get the error message.